# Implementing Google OAuth2 in Xamarin for Google Classrooms

Tags: xamarin, google-classroom

Any idea when a Google Classroom library wil be available for Xamarin? I have tried the .NET and Android library, but the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker and FileDataStore does not exist, and Xamarin doesn't cater for "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" as a redirect url when authenticating with Google Api (OAuth 2). Is there a workaround that anyone know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are unlikely to build any library specifically for Xamarin. The details of our [OAuth2 endpoints](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) are publicly available, so it is in theory possible for you to develop your own implementation.